# JTable: setDefaultRenderer

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, renderer

Why this code can't run correctly? and all item in this JTable have RED COLOR?
i call class *MonCellRenderer* only one times but, it's loop many time. What should i do?

I have class for call jtable :

```
public void Tampil(){
 DataTabel.setNumRows(0);
            try {
                String thn ;
                String bln ;
                String btc ;
                DataTabel.setNumRows(0);
                QueryManajemen q = new QueryManajemen();
                String[] kolom = new String[DataTabel.getColumnCount()];
                for (int a = 0; a < DataTabel.getColumnCount(); a++) {
                    kolom[a] = DataTabel.getColumnName(a);
                }
                String[][] data = //some code;

                String[][] notClean = //some code;

                for (int j = 0; j < notClean.length; j++) {
                    listSearch.add(notClean[j][0].toString());
                }

                **tblBatch.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MonCellRenderer());**
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            }
        }
}
```

then call a class :

```
private List<String> listSearch = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getListSearch() {
        return listSearch;
    }

    public class MonCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                if (column == 0 || listSearch.contains(value)) {
                    setBackground(Color.RED);
                } else {
                    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                }
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `DataTable` and what does it's `getColumnClass` method return?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, beat me, i didn't even notice that line ;)

Comment: DataTable used to show value in tblBatch by query from database...

Comment: All value show in tblBatch is in data[]..

and The value that should be RED is notClean , and i save in list<> listSearch...

Comment: i call only one times but, it's loop many time. What should i do? simple nothing, XxxRenderer is invoked from all mouse and key events in JTable, plus notifiers implemented in JTable and XxxTableModel, important will be only your goal, because I'm bet that there is/are another issue(s) not only empty Renderer

Comment: I think you have red background for all cells because they all in `listSearch`